# How to run store inside foreach loop of Pig script and store in specific paths in HDFS

Tags: foreach, apache-pig, store, multiple-value

I need to store data according its group.
After using `grouped = group events by (name,type);`

I get this when I describe grouped:

```
{group: (name: chararray,type: chararray),events: {(eventDate: chararray, name: chararray,type: chararray)}}
```

## eg of each group and tuples:

- {("group1name,group1type"),(1,b,c),(2,f,e),(1,4,3)}
- {("group2name,group2type"),(2,d,e)}
- {("group3name,group3type"),(3,r,e),(4,s,e)}

so i want to store 
(1,b,c),(2,f,e),(1,4,3) in path "**group1.name/group1.type/datafile**", (2,d,e) in path "**group2.name/group2.type/datafile**" and so on. 
How can I do this?

Comment: you can filter the relation by group and then store it seperately

Comment: @Vikas Could you provide more details please?
I have the grouped data, but I am not sure of storing it in the path created dynamically according to name and type.

Comment: I though you knew about the groups before hand for dynamic storing you can use Multistorage https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html

Comment: Multistorage can be provided with only one column index. But here I'm looking at grouping by 2 values.